# Counter increment for duplicate data from 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 columns in a Table: column1, priority.
Their data looks like following.

```
+--------------------------+
|code | column1 | Priority |
+--------------------------+
| 1001|  1      | 1        |
| 1001|  2      | 1        |
| 1002|  1      | 2        |
| 1002|  2      | 2        |
| 1003|  1      | 3        |
| 1004|  2      | 4        |
| 1005|  1      | 5        |
| 1005|  2      | 5        |
| 1006|  1      | 5        |
| 1006|  2      | 5        |
| 1007|  1      | 5        |
| 1007|  2      | 5        |
+--------------------------+
```

if I concatenate these 2 columns by

```
 select 'con' + column1 + Priority 
 from T1
```

I get following result:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|code | column1 | Priority | (No column name) |
+--------------------------+------------------+
| 1001|  1      | 1        | con11            |
| 1001|  2      | 1        | con21            |
| 1002|  1      | 2        | con12            |
| 1002|  2      | 2        | con22            |
| 1003|  1      | 3        | con13            |
| 1004|  2      | 4        | con24            |
| 1005|  1      | 5        | con15            |
| 1005|  2      | 5        | con25            |
| 1006|  1      | 5        | con15            |
| 1006|  2      | 5        | con25            |
| 1007|  1      | 5        | con15            |
| 1007|  2      | 5        | con25            |
+--------------------------+------------------+
```

But my required values to be like following:
like if concatenated value has already exist than increment in next Priority column value and than concatenate it with column1. e:g if 15 already exists than increment in Priority value to make it 6 than concatenate and get 16 same for 25 to 26.

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|code | column1 | Priority | (No column name) |
+--------------------------+------------------+
| 1001|  1      | 1        | con11            |
| 1001|  2      | 1        | con21            |
| 1002|  1      | 2        | con12            |
| 1002|  2      | 2        | con22            |
| 1003|  1      | 3        | con13            |
| 1004|  2      | 4        | con24            |
| 1005|  1      | 5        | con15            |
| 1005|  2      | 5        | con25            |
| 1006|  1      | 5        | con16            |
| 1006|  2      | 5        | con26            |
| 1007|  1      | 5        | con17            |
| 1007|  2      | 5        | con27            |
+--------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: This sounds like a maintenance nightmare and also prone to error.  Have you looked into using an auto increment column?  That failing, have you considered simply generating the sequence you want on the fly when you query?

Comment: Is it sql server 2008 or 2012? What does c# has to do with any of it?

Comment: Sounds like bad DB design

Comment: @ZoharPeled its 2012

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen these are 2 columns out of round about 50+ columns with no primary key. bus this table has composite key

Comment: "already exist " implies some ordering, but I see no ordering column[s] in the table.

Comment: @Serg let me edit question. this is ordered on Priority and code column let me add code column.

Comment: @Serg question edited.

Comment: Are you using these "con26" values as a sorting argument later on? Because your question's premise is not a good way to approach sorting, I would say that your question is on the verge of becoming an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select code,column1, Priority,  
   concat('con', column1, Priority - 1 + row_number() over(partition by Priority, column1 order by code))
from myTable 
order by code, column1;
```

This will return a row

```
1007    3   5   con35
```

when

```
1007    3   5
```

is added to myTable.  Don't know if it's correct.

**EDIT** if your db compatibility level is 2008 or lower use

```
'con' + cast (column1 as varchar(20)) + cast(Priority - 1 + row_number() over(partition by Priority, column1 order by code) as varchar(20))
```

And if you need `con37` when `1007  3   5` is added, try this

```
select code,column1, Priority, cn ='con' + cast (column1 as varchar(20)) + cast(max(n) over (partition by code) as varchar(20))
from (
   select code,column1, Priority, n=Priority - 1 +  row_number() over(partition by Priority, column1 order by code)
   from myTable 
) t
order by code, column1
```

Comment: 'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

sql server 2012 is installed but 
     SELECT @@VERSION;

is returning Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64) 
 Apr 22 2011 19:23:43 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @Serg still not correct: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=65251ff726dc6de983819a5ad63c6064 it can not be achieved without procedural code ;)

Comment: @serg it is weird he accepted my solution in your answer :D

Comment: @RadimBača, my guess is my  second version with max(n) over ()
was correct.

Comment: @serg 'my guess'? I send you a link where you can see that it is not working correctly and you respond 'my guess is that it is correct'?

Comment: @RadimBača, I see  it, but i can't say is it correct or not, it must be solely OP decision. And if  it's not correct that query with subquery can be easily amended  playing with over().

Comment: Please note that if priority is 9 for 2 rows with the same column1, the First is con39, and the second is con310. (of course, it applies for proirity 8 for 3 rows, 7 for 4 rows etc`).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have a half solution that works only under certain circumstances (for example for your sample data).

```
select column1, priority,
   'con' + CAST(column1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + 
           CAST((row_number() over (partition by column1, priority order by priority) + priority - 1) AS VARCHAR(10))
from tab
```

The problem occurs when you insert for example `(1,6)` into your data then you will have con16 twice. [Here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c962568513c9b1d20f164ddc8ec1dc94) is an example of the solution with problematic data.

Comment: 'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

sql server 2012 is installed but 
     SELECT @@VERSION;

is returning Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64) 
 Apr 22 2011 19:23:43 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @Brainiac hey brainiac, use for example `CAST` instead. Concatenation is a well documented problem

Comment: can u give me example query for SQL Server 2008 R2